# PHP: Dynamically instantiate class and execute function from variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to dynamically instantiate a class and executing a method by getting the class name and the method name from some variables.

This is the code i'm using:

```
public function processAPI() {

    // Require the PHP file that containes the class
    require_once(Settings\Path\Absolute::$engine."/class".$this->endpoint.".php");

    // $this->endpoint is a string containing the class name (this is where i get the error, line 128)
    $endpointClass = new $this->endpoint;

    // $this->verb is the method (function) name
    if(method_exists($endpointClass, $this->verb) > 0) {

        // Executes the class method and returns it. $this->args is an array containing the arguments.
        return $this->response(call_user_func_array($endpointClass->{$this->verb}, $this->args));
    }

    return $this->response('', 400);
}
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in D:\...\webname\resources\engine\classAPI.php on line 128
```

I also tried writing the whole code in the classic way  and it's working without problems.

Comment: Perhaps class `User` is inside a namespace and `$this->endpoint` is not a fully qualified name? Keep in mind that if you have imported a class `User` with `use` then you can straight-instantiate it with `new User` but you *cannot* do the same with `new $class` if `$class` is not fully qualified.

Comment: ` > 0)` what is the point of that?

Comment: @Jon The `classAPI.php` and `classUser.php` are both in the same namespace.

Comment: @ShadowBroker: So that's the problem right there. It doesn't matter if they are in the same namespace, you still have to fully qualify the name if it's in a variable. Try `__NAMESPACE__.'\'.$this->endpoint` as the class to instantiate and see.

Comment: @RPM That simply means `true` i can change it to `== true`.

Comment: @ShadowBroker: See [example #3 here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), it's quite close to your own code.

Comment: @Jon Thank you, I understood that I have the use the fully qualified class name, so i just had to do this:

`$className = __NAMESPACE__ .'\\'.$this->endpoint;`
`$endpointClass = new $className;`

Just add the answer and i'll mark it :)

Comment: @ShadowBroker: Added an answer, glad to help.

Comment: Yeah but you already checking if it is true because `method_exists` returns true or false, no need to check it twice.

Comment: @RPM I'll change it, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create an instance of a class using a variable for the class name you must make sure that the class name is fully qualified (see [related section of the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php)).

In your case, assuming that class API and the class you want to instantiate are members of the same namespace, you can use the `__NAMESPACE__` constant to construct a fully qualified name:

```
$fqcn = __NAMESPACE__ .'\\'.$this->endpoint;
$endpointClass = new $fqcn;
```